# Lucene Proximity Search with multiple words

Tags: lucene, proximity

I am trying to build a query to search an Lucene index of names with name variants.
The index was built with Lucene.NET version 2.9.2

The user enters for example "Margaret White".
Without a name variant option, my query becomes "Margaret White"~1 and it works.

Now, I can look up name variants against both firstname and surname to produce an extended list.
eg.  in this case (and I only include some as an example, since the list can be 100 or more sometimes) we can have

Margaret / Margrett      White / Whyte

The query "margrett white"~1 OR "margaret white"~1 OR "margrett whyte"~1 OR "margaret whyte"~1

gives me the correct result but given a possible 100 x 100 variant combinations, the query string woudl be cumbersome to say the least.

I have tried various ways to achieve a more compact query but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone give me any pointers or alternative approach.  I have control over the index creation process and wonder if there is something I can do at that stage?

Thanks for looking
Roger

Comment: As a follow on to this, I have now implemented a custom analyzer based on [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_custom_analyzer.aspx) which inserts additional name variant tokens into the token stream.  So now my search will find all variants. 
I am now looking for ways to only add the synonym IF it exists on the document to cut down on permutations.  The only way I can access the original text from inside the custom filter is to access the TextReader passed into the analyzer - reading it to get the text takes it to the end of the text with no way to "rewind" to then read for tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the synonym filter in your indexing process instead of at query time. Just map "white", "whyte", ... to some single word; say "white". Same for "Margaret."

Then your query will just be `"margaret white"~1`

Comment: Thanks for your input - I was following the same thought - I am well on the way to creating a custom analyzer which will look up the synonyms during index creation and build additional tokens for the alternatives, all pointing at the same position. As you have pointed out this works well.
The remaining issue I now have to struggle with, is that off highlighting the result.  
I am not quite sure how to approach this - I will probably try to use the result of the explain function to build a list of possible alternatives to try to highlight.

Comment: @RogerDodge: Why would you have issues highlighting? Just translate during both query and index time, then the terms will match exactly.

Comment: The issue is when I search for "margaret white" and the doc contains "margrett white". I dont know which combination caused the hit.  I am using the FastVectorHighlighter which can just highlight each individual words.  This, for me, is incorrect, since I cannot have a highlighted term "White" for example if it is next to Thomas White.  I am now overriding the FieldQuery.flatten method in the highlighter to build new phrases made up of all permutations of the two firstname/surname terms.  The list can be quite large and affect performance so I am looking for ways to cut this down.

Comment: @RogerDodge: I don't understand why translating *both* the query and the index would fail. You might want to try asking another question to open it to a wider audience.

Comment: It doesnt fail in the search - it is very fast - and it doesnt actually fail in highlighting - it just generates a HUGE no of possible search terms to match which impacts performance greatly.
Once I can detail the issue correctly I will open up a new question. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and solved it by writing my own query parser and manually instantiating query primitives.  Writing your own query parser is not necessarily easy, but it gives you a lot of flexibility. In my new query language, I use within/N to specify a proximity query.  With it, the following complex queries become possible:

```
margaret within/3 white
margaret within/3 (white or whyte)
```

Or even more complex queries

```
("first name" within/3 margaret) within/10 ("last name" within/3 (white or whyte))
```

Comment: This is interesting. Can you post your query parser here?

Comment: It's used in production (see here: https://www.docketalarm.com/search/), but it's not in a state that I'm ready to share on the open web. If you're interested in it, shoot me an email on my profile.

Comment: Thanks, but at the end I found exactly what I was looking for with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10983841/2091700

Comment: I looked at your link.  Awsome!