# ""black lab*" "pet shop""~5 in Lucene (proximity search with multi-word phrases)

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How can I do a proximity search for two multi-word phrases in Lucene.  For example, I want to find all 
black lab* (black labrador, black labradoodle, etc) withing 5 words of the phrase "pet shop".  Which analyzer should I be using?  Which query parser would be recommended?  I'm working with Lucene.NET.  I've ported the ComplexPhraseQueryParser from Java to C#, but that parser doesn't seem to be doing the trick (or perhaps I'm just using it wrong).  I'm just getting started with Lucene, so your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [SpanQuery](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) for this:

```
new SpanNearQuery(
    new SpanQuery[] {
        new SpanNearQuery(
            new SpanQuery[] {
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "black")),
                new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<WildcardQuery>(new WildcardQuery(new Term(FIELD, "lab*"))),
            },
            0,
            true),
        new SpanNearQuery(
            new SpanQuery[] {
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "pet")),
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "shop")),
            },
            0,
            true),
    },
    5,
    true);
```

The default Lucene `QueryParser` doesn't support span queries, but you could try the [Surround query parser](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/22/exploring-query-parsers/). I couldn't find much else in the way of documentation.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412076/26003) and [this blog post](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) useful.

Comment: is the SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper available in lucene.net 3.0.3 ?

Comment: I don't think so. It would be in this directory if it were: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/tree/3.0.3/src/core/Search/Spans

Comment: @Ricard Poole True. Went to have a look and tried to port it to C#. There's too many dependencies tho.

Comment: @pelican_george It's available in the latest version of Lucene.Net: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Core/Search/Spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.cs

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [set the slop](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html#setSlop%28int%29).